# How to get item by inputed ID(In Action Script+Php)

Tags: php, actionscript

was troubling with this issue around a week or two, so please if someone know how to solve this problem -please

i have a sort of a viewer like this
![MDL2 Viewer][1]That i found on a web - it acctualy solve most of my problem but in different way that i expected,

It adds a 3D model in scene - that i currently selected from Grid-list. IT doesnt store the model ID to the adress 
of the model like: `modelFile="data/modelfiles/Sphere.mdl"` its binds selected item, to its adress,
ActionScript code

```
particles_ary[prevIndex].load(myDataGrid.selectedItem.address);
```

MyDataGrid is just a xml collection with markers(Name, Adress to model, Adress to skin,etc) 
that is readed by a method ReadXMl, that is adding these markers to MyDataGrid.

But i need to write the id off the model and when i press button(Input Model), it makes some sort of trigger
that looks in the markers xml,
find the id(marker) that i inputed, and bind to the adress(of the model).
something like this

```
load(myDataGrid.ItemArray[InputedItemIndex].address);
```

Maybe thats some wrong method, but all i want is not to have an item by selection, but have it by recived ID from
user input.

Thats acctualy not whole point of problem - because i acctualy not need most of this method only for Action script
acctualy i need it to work in html php window, like it works in Wow Model viewer, by some {GET} method that stores
iD of the item that is selected by user in php, and handled to Action Script that acctualy shows model that user
Choosed.

Sorry for my bad english, as if there is some more explanation i would to explain it more, as im troubling
with this thing in more then 2 weeks, hope someone would help me out, or maybe there is some source for this kind
of task - to view models in web.
thx!

Answer (score 0):

Thx i cleared this out by searching by proper keyword in stackoverflow

and the method i looked out is looks like this

`particles_ary[prevIndex].load(myDataGrid.dataProvider.getItemAt(0).address,myCarSkin, 10, 3);`

you can close it.